# How to use Y- Combinator; why does this infinite recursion return 9?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, y-combinator, fixpoint-combinators

## Y - Combinator

I've been trying to learn about Y - Combinators *(an explanation on that would be lovely as well)* and came across an example from this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Derivation_of_the_Y_combinator). An in depth explanation on the subject would be much appreciated in either Haskell or Python. Pleaaase!

## Code

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = f (fix f)
```

## Problem

The function called`fix` returns `9` when `fix` is applied to `(\x -> 9)` and I have no clue why; when I follow the stack I visualize `f(f ... (fix f) ...)`.

```
>> fix (\x -> 9)
>> 9
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all: the `fix` function you have is a fixed-point combinator *implemented with direct recursion*. The Y combinator is a *particular* fixed-point combinator that *does not need syntactic recursion* so it accomplished the same thing as `fix` but in a different way.

If you're curious, you can look at [how to implement the Y combinator in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273413/y-combinator-in-haskell) here on SO. It's a bit tricky with static types—it needs a recursive type to work.

As for your second question, the code works thanks to laziness. If you apply `(\ x -> 9)` to *anything*, that thing will never get evaluated. Try this:

```
λ> (\ x -> 9) (error "fail")
9
```

This includes the recursive call in the definition of `fix`. Look at what happens when you replace the outer-most `f` with `(\ x -> 9)` in the definition of `fix`:

```
(\ x -> 9) (fix f)
```

Following exactly the same logic as the version with `error`, the recursive call *never gets evaluated* and you just get a `9` out.