# Haskell `let` bindings in lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, recursion, let, lambda-calculus, letrec

I want to understand how `let` bindings work in Haskell (or maybe lambda calculus, if the Haskell implementation differs?)

I understand from reading [Write you a Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/003_lambda_calculus.html) that this is valid for a single `let` binding.

```
let x = y in e == (\x -> e) y
```

This makes sense to me, since it's consistent with how bindings work in the lambda calculus. Where I'm confused is using multiple `let` bindings, where one binding can reference the bindings above. I will provide a trivial example.

Original code:

```
let times x y = x * y
    square x = times x x
in square 5
```

My guess at the implementation:

```
(\square times -> square 5) (\x -> times x x) (\x -> x * x)
```

This seems not to work because `times` is not defined when square is called by the lambda. However, this can by solved by this implementation:

```
(\square -> square 5) ((\times x -> times x x) (\x -> x * x))
```

Is this the proper way to implement this binding, at least in the lambda calculus?

Comment: you probably need to define `let times x y = x * y ...` otherwise doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @karakfa Thank you! Small mental error on my part. Got ahead myself! I will edit. :)

Comment: Haskell's `let` is not `let`, it is `letrec`.

Comment: @WillNess If `let` is actually `letrec`, does that mean `fix` is applied to every bindings, or only recursive ones?

Comment: every and always. in theory at least; a compiler might realize there's no recursion and optimize. and we don't actually have to use fix. recursion can be implemented directly by the implementation, under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

The `times`/`square` example can be expressed in terms of lambda functions using scoping:

```
(\times -> (\square -> square 5)(\x -> times x x))(\x y -> x * y)
```

But scoping isn't enough for recursive or mutually recursive let-bindings like

```
let ones = 1 : ones in take 5 ones

let even n = n == 0 || odd (abs n - 1)
    odd n  = n /= 0 && even (abs n - 1)
in even 7
```

In the lambda calculus you can define the [y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) for recursion as

```
(\f -> (\x -> f (x x))(\x -> f (x x)))
```

This lets you define functions and values in terms of themselves. That formulation isn't legal haskell due to typing constraints [but there are ways around that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273413/y-combinator-in-haskell).

Using the y-combinator lets us express the above let-bindings using the lambda calculus:

```
(\ones -> take 5 ones)((\f -> (\x -> f (x x))(\x -> f (x x)))(\ones -> 1 : ones))

(\evenodd -> evenodd (\x y -> x) 7)((\f -> (\x -> f (x x))(\x -> f (x x)))(\evenodd c -> c (\n -> n == 0 || evenodd (\x y -> y) (abs n - 1)) (\n -> n /= 0 && evenodd (\x y -> x) (abs n - 1))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was already aware of using `fix` along with the extra lambda to do recursion, but hadn't seen mutually recursive bindings done, so thanks! That's really cool. With you scoping example, I see that it's like my failed implementation, but with extra brackets. If I understand currently, l.c. is right associative, and thus these two expressions should evaluate the same, yes? Your example does work in GHCi. It's always cool to see that so much can be done with just the typed lambda calculus.

Comment: Oh, I see the difference. I did `\square times ->` instead of `\times -> (\square`. This makes more sense. I still don't really understand why the brackets are needed. Maybe you could clarify?

Comment: All u need is **U**: `Y = U . (. U)`. :) (well, **B** too).

Answer (score 3):

Note that multiple `let` bindings can be reduced to a single one, defining a pair (tuple, in the general case). E.g. we can rewrite

```
let times x y = x * y
    square x = times x x
in square 5
```

as

```
let times = \x y -> x * y
    square = \x -> times x x
in square 5
```

then

```
let (times, square) = (\x y -> x * y, \x -> times x x)
in square 5
```

then, if wanted,

```
let pair = (\x y -> x * y, \x -> fst pair x x)
in snd pair 5
```

After that, we can apply the usual lambda calculus translation. If the pair definition ends up to be recursive, as in the case above, we need a fixed point combinator.

```
(\pair -> snd pair 5) (fix (\pair -> (\x y -> x * y, \x -> fst pair x x)))
```

Note that this translation does not play along type inference algorithms, which handle `let` in a special way, introducing polymorphism. This is not important if we only care about the dynamic aspects of our program, though.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question to maybe provide a helpful perspective to those who visit this question.

We want to implement the following program with two let bindings:

```
let times a b = a * b
    square x = times x x
in square 5
```

To start with, let's simplify this to the essence of what we want:

```
square 5
```

Simple enough. However, `square` in this case is undefined! Well, we can bind it using the mechanism our language provides us with - a lambda. This gives us `(\ square -> square 5) (\x -> times x x)`. Now `square` is defined, but its cousin `times` is not... Well, we need another lambda! Our final program should look like this:

```
(\times -> (\square -> square 5) (\x -> times x x)) (\a b -> a * b)
```

Notice that the `(\times -> ...)` completely encloses our last step, so that `times` will be in scope as it is bound. This is consistent with the answer given by @rampion, and reduces as follows:

```
(\times -> (\square  -> square 5) (\x -> times x x)) (\a b -> a * b) =>
(\square -> square 5) (\x -> (\a b -> a * b) x x)                    =>
(\square -> square 5) (\x -> (\b -> x * b) x)                        => 
(\square -> square 5) (\x -> x * x)                                  => 
(\x -> x * x) 5                                                      =>
5 * 5                                                                => 
25
```

If the `square` function had not depended on `times`, we could have easily written `(\times square -> ....`. The dependency means that we must nest these two environments, one containing `times`, and another inside of that which can use its definition.

Thanks for all of your help! I'm blown away by the simplicity and power of the lambda calculus.